# Модифицировать регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, строки

Всем привет! Есть регулярное выражение,которое убирает все знаки препинания из строки:

```
import re
str = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',str)
```

str - искомая строка. Как модифицировать данное регулярное выражение чтобы оно убирало все знаки препинания, кроме `'`(одинарной кавычки)?

Comment: `r"[^\w\s']"`...

Answer (score 2):

Убирает все знаки препинания кроме `'`:

```
import string

s = "test, string    h. '11'"

punct_dict = dict.fromkeys(string.punctuation)
punct_dict.pop("'")

print(s.translate(s.maketrans(punct_dict)))
```

Comment: не лучшая идея использовать в качестве идентификатора переменной название типа.